# Changing HTTP method in RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, servlet-3.0, requestdispatcher

How do I change HTTP method in `javax,servlet.RequestDispatcher`?

I have some old service APIs that support GET and POST, The new version supports DELETE method for removing a record which used to happen through POST earlier.

We are decommissioning old version APIs by setting RequestDispatcher.forward() for old end points (stop gap arrangement until clients change). everything was cool except this POST to DELETE mapping.

Any solution there for this problem without adding POST end point for delete operation in new API?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I agree using the next layer after your servlets would be a better choice, this is interesting.  It use to be common to wrap an incoming request to add request based functionality (IE: auth state, etc).  The *[HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://HttpServletRequestWrapper)* was used to accomplish this.  You could do the following if you just need to change the method:

```
class PostDeleteAdapter extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
  public String getMethod(){ return "POST"; }
}
```

You may also change other aspects of the incoming request if you need to further adapt the request.  This may play well with your servlet containers *RequestDispatcher*, however it's dependent upon the container entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it using servlet API. You can do what you want creating a new request, processing it's response and sending it back through the original response (in the servlet).

Some http clientes might help you. See Apache HTTP client:

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/delete.html)